# How can I get the results of many queries into 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

How can I get the results of my query below in one single result?

As you can see in my example, I am getting multiple query results individually.

The code is:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE @i < 15
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
  Select @i 
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking ??

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 as start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT start+1 FROM CTE
    WHERE start < 15
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

If yes, the method is called *Recursive CTE* which could also pronounced as *Tally tables*. Tally tables are one way that you may be able to avoid using a *loop* or a *CURSOR* 
However, use *MAXRECURSION* option/hint to prevent run infinitely, SQL Server  default recursion level is 100.

Comment: This is it. What do you call this method sir? I'm kinda new to this things  and i'm trying to learn what I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can hold each record to a table variable also. Declare the table variable outside the `WHILE` loop and insert each row at each iteration.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @i int = 0;
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE([i] INT);

WHILE @i < 15
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1;
    INSERT INTO @tbl([i])
    SELECT @i;
END

SELECT [i] FROM @tbl;
```